# How to add the Layout to QStackedLayout?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyside6

I'm trying to add some layouts to QStackedLayout.

```py
self.rightLayout = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()
self.rightLayout.addItem(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
```

However, it throws the warning:

> QStackedLayout::addItem: Only widgets can be added

It is possible to use QStackedLayout to manipulate another layouts? Or may be some other way to switch layouts should be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a QWidget as a container:

```
container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)

self.rightLayout = QtWidgets.QStackedLayout()
self.rightLayout.addWidget(container)
```